# jquery array with one empty string value

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I have code like this:

```
var form_data = {
        services: $("input[id^='campaign_cbx_']:checked").serialize(),

                };
```

And if no campaign_cbx_something checkbox is checked i would like to have an epmty array, but in php I have array with 0 index and empty string value. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommendable, but how about

```
var data = $("input[id^='campaign_cbx_']:checked").serialize();
var form_data = {
   services: data?data:"campaign_cbx[0]=" 
};
```

I strongly suggest your PHP can handle empty data